# Semantic UI : how to place an button at the bottom of a column?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

This is a very simple question, but after some research, I can't find a way to do it properly: I have a grid with 3 columns in Semantic UI and the content of each column has a specific height. I try to add a button at the bottom of each column, but "bottom aligned" doesn't work. 
Someone has a clue ?
Here is an example:

```
<div class="ui basic segment">
  <div class="ui divided grid container">
    <div class="three column row">
      <div class="column">
        Hello <br>
        fdsfsd <br>
        fsfsd <br>
        fdsfsd <br>
        fsfsd <br>
        fsfsd <br>
        fdsfsd <br>
        fsfsd <br>
        fs
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="segments">
          <div class="ui segment">Hello</div>
          <div class="ui bottom aligned segment">
            fdsfsdf
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Where is your button?

Comment: sorry about that: I meant a segment... I know that for a button you can attach it at the bottom with "ui bottom attached button". PS: I would like to edit my question to modify the title (and the content) but I don't know how to do it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go about it is to use a flexbox inside the column to position the content and the `.ui.segment` div

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/batrasoe/vq84trys/4/

```
<div class="ui  segment">
  <div class="ui divided grid container">
    <div class="three column stretched row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="segment-wrapper">
          <div class="content">

          </div>
          <div class="ui bottom segment">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="segment-wrapper">
          <div class="content">

          </div>
          <div class="ui bottom segment">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="column">
        <div class="segment-wrapper">
          <div class="content">

          </div>
          <div class="ui bottom segment">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
    .segment-wrapper {
  background-color: #DDD;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.ui.bottom.segment {
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sarthak ! Almost there. The only problem left is that I can't use a min-height since the height depends of the amount of text and the screen size... Would you have a workaround for my example ?

Comment: updated answer. Just remove the min-height property from the CSS and add the keyword `stretched` in the div that has class `row`